# looping through a json tree object and create new array

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

Is there a way good way JS/ES6 to loop through an object and it's children and creating new object tree array.

I have this json tree object:

```
[
{
    id: "001",
    deparmentsIds: [
        "002",
        "003"
    ],
    details: {
        parentDeparmentsId: null,
        name: "Top"
    }
},
{
    id: "002",
    deparmentsIds:[
        "004"
    ],
    details: {
        parentDeparmentsId: ["001"],
        name: "Operations"
    }
},
{
    id: "003",
    deparmentsIds:[]
    details: {
        parentDeparmentsId: ["001"],
        name: "Support"
    }
},
{
    id: "004",
    deparmentsIds:[]
    details: {
        parentDeparmentsId: ["002"],
        name: "Support operations"
    }
}
```

]

I want to create new object array tree that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the expected structure in JS and not html?

Comment: The html is only for showing the structure.

Comment: True and we get the structure required. But how to represent the same in JS is what we need.

Comment: I understand now what you mean... maybe somehting like this?  deparments = [{ top: [ "operations", " support" ] }] .. what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` and `map` method to create nested object structure.

```js
const data = [{"id":"001","deparmentsIds":["002","003"],"details":{"parentDeparmentsId":null,"name":"Top"}},{"id":"002","deparmentsIds":["004"],"details":{"parentDeparmentsId":"001","name":"Operations"}},{"id":"003","deparmentsIds":[],"details":{"parentDeparmentsId":"001","name":"Support"}},{"id":"004","deparmentsIds":[],"details":{"parentDeparmentsId":"002","name":"Support operations"}}]

function tree(input, parentId) {
  return input.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.id == parentId || parentId == undefined && e.details.parentDeparmentsId == null) {
      const children = [].concat(...e.deparmentsIds.map(id => tree(input, id)))
      const obj = {
        [e.details.name]: children
      }
      r.push(obj)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = tree(data)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all information in an object with a single loop and return only the nodes with no parent.

```js
function getTree(data, root) {
    var o = {};
    data.forEach(({ id, details: { parentDeparmentsId: parent, name } }) => {
        var temp = { id, name };
        if (o[id] && o[id].children) {
            temp.children = o[id].children;
        }
        o[id] = temp;
        o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(temp);
    });
    return o[root].children;
}

var data = [{ id: "001", deparmentsIds: ["002", "003"], details: { parentDeparmentsId: null, name: "Top" } }, { id: "002", deparmentsIds: ["004"], details: { parentDeparmentsId: ["001"], name: "Operations" } }, { id: "003", deparmentsIds: [], details: { parentDeparmentsId: ["001"], name: "Support" } }, { id: "004", deparmentsIds: [], details: { parentDeparmentsId: ["002"], name: "Support operations" } }],
    tree = getTree(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```